# Core Data addPersistentStoreWithType return nil, but error is nil too

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm creating a `NSPersistentStore` with the code below.

```
NSPersistentStore * pc = [persistentCoordinator 
                             addPersistentStoreWithType:EncryptedStoreType
                                          configuration:nil 
                                                    URL:databaseURL
                                                options:options 
                                                  error:error];

if (*error)
{
    NSLog(@"Unable to add persistent store.");
    NSLog(@"Error: %@\n%@\n%@", *error, [*error userInfo], [*error localizedDescription]);
}
```

The value of `options` is

```
{
    EncryptedStore = SQLite;
    EncryptedStoreDatabaseLocation = 
 "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0C27F628-3FF0-467F-8EF1-5974EBBD3620/Documents/DBEncrypted.sqlite";
    EncryptedStorePassphrase = "xxxxxxxxredactedxxxxxxx";
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSSQLitePragmasOption =     {
        synchronous = OFF;
    };
}
```

At this point `*error` is `nil` and `pc` is `nil` too.

According to Apple's documentation if the function returns nil should be an error. Does anyone saw it before?

The `EncryptedStoreType` is from https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data

The error only happens if we are migrating the Data Store

**EDIT:**
Full code of method:

```
+ (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)makeStoreWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options managedObjectModel:(NSManagedObjectModel *)objModel error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator * persistentCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:objModel];

    //  NSString* appSupportDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    BOOL backup = YES;
    NSURL *databaseURL;
    id dburl = [options objectForKey:EncryptedStoreDatabaseLocation];
    if(dburl != nil) {
        if ([dburl isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
            databaseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[options objectForKey:EncryptedStoreDatabaseLocation]];
            backup = NO;
        }
        else if ([dburl isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]){
            databaseURL = dburl;
            backup = NO;
        }
    }

    if (backup){
        NSString *dbNameKey = (__bridge NSString *)kCFBundleNameKey;
        NSString *dbName = NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary[dbNameKey];
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *applicationSupportURL = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtURL:applicationSupportURL withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
        databaseURL = [applicationSupportURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[dbName stringByAppendingString:@".sqlite"]];

    }

    [persistentCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:EncryptedStoreType configuration:nil URL:databaseURL
        options:options error:error];

    if (*error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Unable to add persistent store.");
        NSLog(@"Error: %@\n%@\n%@", *error, [*error userInfo], [*error localizedDescription]);
    }

    return persistentCoordinator;
}
```

I call it in

```
- (void) initCoreDataProperties
{
    NSError *error;

    // Creating the Managed Object Model from momd
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:TBCoreDataModelFileName withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    // Creating the Encrypted Store Persistent Coordinator
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [EncryptedStore makeStoreWithOptions: [self persistentStoreOptions]
                                                    managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel
                                                                 error: &error];
```

Comment: Update your question with how you call the `makeStoreWithOptions:managedObjectModel:error:` method and include how you declare the `error` value you pass in.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Hoping you might have resolved this issue. If not, we should be adding “sqlite3.h” and “sqlite3.c” files to project to resolve persistent store defect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, do not check the error for an error state.  Only check the return of the call to `-addPersistentStoreWithType...`.  The error can be populated even in a non-error condition.

Your code looks fine so I suspect if you turned off the encrypted store and used an Apple provided `SQLite` store then it would work fine.  Which means the issue is with that third party code.

Since the third party code is not providing you with an error or a `NSPersistentStore` then it is failing poorly and you need to open a bug against the code base so that the author can address it.

Or you can walk through that third part code and see where it is failing and why.

Comment: Thank you! https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data/issues/197 - I created there.